# How to Change Multiple Checkbox Query to Multiple Chosen jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-chosen

I have a multiple checkbox query, as below

```
  <span style="width:276px;display:inline-block;">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="sub_category_id = '1''">Name1</span>

  <span style="width:276px;display:inline-block;">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="sub_category_id = '2'">Name2</span>

  <span style="width:276px;display:inline-block;">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="sub_category_id = '3'">Name3</span>

  <span style="width:276px;display:inline-block;">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="sub_category_id = '4'">Name4</span>
```

then

```
 <?php
 $names = implode(' or ', (array)$_POST['check_list'.$i]);
 echo $names;
 ?>
```

I got part of my query.

```
sub_category_id = '1'' or sub_category_id = '2' or sub_category_id = '3' or sub_category_id = '4'
```

Using chosen Jquery, I´m able to retrieve the MySQL data (Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4), as below:

```
   <select name="sub_category_id[]" id="sub_category_id[]" multiple     class="chosen-select" tabindex="8">
   <option value="">Selecione...</option>
    <?php foreach ($arrEstados as $value => $name) {
      echo "<option value='{$value}'>{$name}</option>";
    }?>
  </select>

  $names = $_POST['sub_category_id'];
  $query=implode('sub_category_id=', $names);
  echo $query;
```

But the 'or' is missing.  I don´t have great skills in PHP, so I ask: Is this the right way to get my query? I´m not using PDO or mysqli.

Comment: so where/how is `$arrEstados` produced?

Comment: Learn about [IN clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm). Then you can get rid of that "or" things and values of option tags can be just numbers.

Comment: Marc is the mysql query to retrieve the data:  $sql = "SELECT * FROM sub_categories where cat_id=1 order by sub_cat_name";
$res = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$num = mysql_num_rows($res);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
  $dados = mysql_fetch_array($res);$arrEstados[$dados['sub_cat_id']] = $dados['sub_cat_name'];

Answer (score 0):

change your html select element to follow this:

```
<select name="check_list[sub_category_id][]" id="sub_category_id[]" multiple     class="chosen-select" tabindex="8">
    <option value="">Selecione...</option>
    <?php
        foreach ($arrEstados as $value => $name) {
            echo "<option value='{$value}'>{$name}</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

doing this will create an array like this in your $_POST:

```
$_POST => Array
    (
        [check_list] => Array
            (
                [sub_category_id] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2
                        [1] => 3
                    )

            )

    )
```

then change your PHP like so:

```
<?php
        $names = isset($_POST['check_list']) && isset($_POST['check_list']['sub_category_id']) ? $_POST['check_list']['sub_category_id'] : NULL;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ";
        if(!is_null($names)){
            foreach($names as $i => $name){
                if($i !== 0){
                    $query .= " OR ";
                }
                $query .= "sub_category_id = '$name'";
            }
        }
        echo($query);
        //Output: SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE sub_category_id = '2' OR sub_category_id = '3'   
    }
?>
```

you might need to change the query to fit your application, but this will help get in you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin suggest de http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm turns the simple way to solve it. That´s what i did:

```
 <select chosen still the same...>

 $sub_category_1 = $_POST['sub_category_id'];
 $query=implode(',', $sub_category_1);

 $sql = "Select * from table WHERE sub_category_id IN($query)";
```